# On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements- HibernateItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am newbie to Spring batch.I was trying to use `HibernateItemWriter` for writing into destination database.I am getting following exception when executing my batch job.

Following is the exception and code of my application

`HibernateItemWriter` configuration :-

```
@StepScope
@Bean
public ItemWriter<NewEmployee> hibernateEmployeeItemWriter() throws IOException {
        HibernateItemWriter<NewEmployee> itemWriter = new HibernateItemWriter<>();
        itemWriter.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        itemWriter.setClearSession(true);
        return itemWriter;
}
```

Session factory and Transaction Manager code

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException{
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(configuration.getDataSource());
   // factoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.qiwkreport.qiwk.etl.domain");
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.qiwkreport.qiwk.etl.domain");
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryBean;
}


@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Entity class code :-

```
    Entity
    @Table(name = "NEWEMPLOYEE")
    public class NewEmployee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;
@Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "LASTNAME")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "VILLAGE")
private String village;
@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;
@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;
@Column(name = "DISTRICT")
private String district;
@Column(name = "STATE")
private String state;
@Column(name = "PINCODE")
private String pincode;
@Column(name = "MANAGERID")
private String managerid;
@Column(name = "MANAGERNAME")
private String managerName;
```

Exception Trace :-

```
       017-08-30 20:22:22.919 DEBUG 9560 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update NEWEMPLOYEE set CITY=?, DISTRICT=?, FIRSTNAME=?, LASTNAME=?, MANAGERNAME=?, MANAGERID=?, PINCODE=?, STATE=?, STREET=?, VILLAGE=? where ID=?
2017-08-30 20:22:22.930  INFO 9560 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2017-08-30 20:22:22.935 ERROR 9560 --- [nio-9000-exec-7] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step employeeSlaveStep in job EmployeeJob

org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3134)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3013)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3393)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter.write(HibernateItemWriter.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
```

Comment: For starters you are using the wrong transaction manager (JPA instead of plain Hibernate) and you haven't coupled the `SessionFactory` to a transaction manager at all. Also why not use the `JpaItemWriter` instead of the plain hibernate one (as that is apparently what you actually want to do).

Comment: Might be related this issue -> https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13050